# Removing three zeroes from any quintic

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to understand: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschirnhaus_transformation

But all I know how to do is to remove $a_4$ coefficient from $x^5 + a_4 x^4 + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0 = 0$. See code in Python language below.

What calculations I need to do for determining the translations for removing 2 zeroes $(a_4, a_3) = (0,0)$?

And in the last case, if I want $x^5 + b_1 x + b_0 = 0$, with 3 zeroes, how do I determine the Tchirnhausen parameters?

Is this too hard to program removing $a_{n-1}, a_{n-2}, a_{n-3}$ for any natural degree $n \ge 5$?

See also this code in Python: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XxcsllczeqMo0EgA46PoAXwis4--qJuM/view?usp=sharing

See also this paper I have found. It seems it's an answer for $n = 5$:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005026v1

```
def Tschirnhaus1(a4, a3, a2, a1, a0):
   #y = x + a
   return a4/5

def Tschirnhaus2(a4, a3, a2, a1, a0):
   #y = x^2 + ax + b
   return a, b

def Tschirnhaus3(a4, a3, a2, a1, a0):
   #y = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c
   return a, b, c
```